# Touch display doesn't turn on when system wakes

Tags: windows-8.1, display, sleep

I have a windows 8.1 system being used as digital signage. I would like it to wake up automatically in the mourning and sleep at night. Sleeping at night works fine, and having task scheduler run `echo hello` at specific time in the mourning does wake the computer up, but the display stays off. A single tap makes it turn back on.
Any ideas on how to resolve this, if you need any more information I can post it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your touch display function is not in the  startup program folder.
For adding this program in satartup program please follow this steps:

Goto **start** and search for the program which you use for starting the function.

Right click on it,where you will found pop menu in which click on **'open file location'**.

This let you to the either the installation directory and shortcut menu folder. **Create shrotcut** of this program and copy it.

Paste it into following location (make sure you are pasting shotcut of that program).

C:\Users\"**your_username**"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Restart the computer.

You will found that your touch display function is satated automatically.